# Simplifying a function that performs operations on one data frame based on values in another data frame

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have two data frames `dat1` and `dat2`:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a","b","c"), each =100),
                   dist = rep(1:100, times = 3),
                   var1 = rnorm(300),
                   var2 = rnorm(300))
dat2 <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c"),
                   value = c(42,56,39))
```

the `value` column in `dat2` contains the index of the values through which I would like to subset in `dat1`. I wrote the following function `getv` to do this subset and perform this operation using that value:

```r
getk <- 
  function(id, value){
    x <- dplyr::filter(dat1,  id == id)
    x <- x[1:value, ]
    k = 10*(value^(2/9))
    k = ceiling(k)
    k
  }
getk(a,42)
```

I want to add a line to the function that assigns the correct `value` from `dat2` to a new object `v`, so that I don't have to feed the function the `id` and `value` every time. I cannot figure out how to say essentially: "if I give tell you I want to do this for `a`, assign the number from `dat2$value` that goes with `filter(dat2, id==a)` to the object `v`"

In other words, my function will turn into something close to this:

```r
getk <- 
  function(id){
    x <- dplyr::filter(dat1,  id == id)
    v <- #the value in dat2
    x <- x[1:v, ]
    k = 10*(v^(2/9))
    k = ceiling(k)
    k
  }
#after which I could just do this and get the same answer as above:
getk(a)
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```
v <- dat2$value[dat2$id == id]
```

But note it will only work in your function if you use `getk("a")` since `a` is not an object.